# Where do you put common data setters in DDD for update/insert?

Tags: php, service, repository, domain-driven-design

I have a question regarding Domain Driven Design. Let's imagine a simple scenario.

I have an Entity called "User" that has some properties. One of these properties is "date_created", "date_modified" and "last_login_ip".

Let's say we have a form that creates a user and if the create is successful, it authenticates him.

1. The controller gets the POST data
2. Sends the post data to a UsersService via the method "createAndAuthenticateUser"
3. The service receives the data, validates it (doing it here and NOT in the entity because the validation is tied to repositories, such as to validate if the email already exists, etc).
4. If the validation is OK, it creates a new Entity, assigns the data to it and then sends the entity to the repository to save it. The repository then saves this user in a datasource.

So far so good. The problem here is that, the date_created/date_modified/last_login_ip have to be set in this service method.

What if I want to set the date_modified ANYTIME when the user object is updated (for instance,at login I want to update the date_modified, at user update i want it again, at user creation I want it again.

Logically, my own answer would be to put this in the repository like...

(meta code here sort of, the syntax doesn't matter)

```
function save($User) {

if (!$User->id) $User->date_created = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS';

$User->date_modified = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS';

$DataSource->Save($User);

return $User;
}
```

However, from what I've been reading, the repository should always just map data between the caller and the datasource (and the reverse) and that's it. It should never SET data or anything like that.

Of course, you could tell me this is a behavior, so I could have a behavior that says $User->markAsUpdated() which would just set the date_modified property. But again, this means that this method must be called from more than one place, instead of having a centralized place to do it. I don't see the benefit of NOT having this code in the repository.

Any ideas?

Comment: This does not address your main issue, but if you are using Mysql then consider using "on update current_timestamp" at the db level, other rdbms' may have similar table definition settings.

Comment: I thought of that also, but I am thinking more of a generic issue. I could easily think of other examples that are not specific to dates, so the mysql function would not help in this case. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the concept of last login ip is actually central to your user for some reason, then it's valid to update the user on login.  The fact that you're expressing concern about performing that update to save the last login IP implies that it's not really a user concept, but a security, audit, or otherwise-external-to-user concept.

As for setting the modify and create dates, I'd make the same argument.  If it's a requirement of the system that the user both maintain and expose that information, then create a private method on the user that each public method calls when it modifies the state, which will set the modify date.  If it's not, then you pretty much have two options - either create an auditing service that is notified of the update and keeps its own audit record, or have the repository set the fields when it updates the record.

Comment: So you are saying that the repository is actually OK to set some properties on the entity? It also makes sense to me for it to do that, since it would be centralized into a single point. Since I *know* that the date_modified should always be updated to the current date when the user object is changed.The only way to change him (and persist of course) is via the repository method save().

I know that DDD is about separation of concerns. Why are you saying I am mixing up stuff? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you may have a valid reason for the `User` object to know what its last login IP is, but the fact that you're concerned about updating the User to save it tells me that your requirement is likely not that the `User` know what its last login IP was, but that some other part of the system know that.  If that's the case, then put the last login IP where it's actually needed, and have the service that manages logins publish a notification that the user has logged in somehow.

Comment: Ok. I will accept your answer but more for the 2nd comment. You could update it the answer with the comment also perhaps? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.  I'll clarify my answer in that direction.